# How to use CSS :hover to make extra div block elements display?

Tags: html, css

I have several `<div>` displayed as boxes that represent a certain company. When they appear on the page, they look like this:

[image: example]

When the user hovers over the box, it should display 2 more boxes below that are links to "product info" or "contact info". These boxes can be interracted with and should disappear if the user moves the mouse outside of the main box or 2 boxes that were just shown. See below:

[image: example2]

How can I make these "info prompt" divs display on `box:hover`? Is it possible to create a "CSS rule" of sorts so that when I hover the main box that these will display?

I would really like to do this without JavaScript if possible.

**EDIT:** When the extra prompts aren't there, the box height should be shortened so there isn't obvious extra white space at the bottom (where they would normally be).

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/q8csa10v/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="catalog-display">

            <div class="catalog-item">
                <div class="item-title">&#9825;</div>
                <img class="supplier-logo" src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png" alt="<supplier name> logo" />
                <div class="supplier-name">Ubuntu Office Supply</div>
                <div class="supplier-info">
                    <span>Product Info</span>
                    <span>Contact Info</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="catalog-item">
                <div class="item-title">&#9825;</div>
                <img class="supplier-logo" src="http://silvercreekart.weebly.com/uploads/3/7/3/0/37300503/9869404.png" alt="<supplier name> logo" />
                <div class="supplier-name">Silvercreek Products</div>
                <div class="supplier-info">
                    <span>Product Info</span>
                    <span>Contact Info</span>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.catalog-display {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.catalog-item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 215px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #3fa9db;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

    position: relative;
}

    .catalog-item .item-title {
        background-color: #656262;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .catalog-item .supplier-logo {
        height: 80px;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }

    .catalog-item .supplier-name {
        color: #0E80B4;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
        border-top: 1px solid #656262;
    }

    .catalog-item .supplier-info {
        color: #656262;
        font-weight: bold;

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;

        border-top: 1px solid #656262;
    }

        .catalog-item .supplier-info span {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 46px;
            width: 73px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
            .catalog-item .supplier-info span:first-child {
                background-color: #d1e8f0;
            }

            .catalog-item .supplier-info span:last-child {
                background-color: #E5EDD6;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the initial height of your box to `175px` and set on `:hover` the full height

```
.catalog-item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #3fa9db;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    transition: height .4s;
}
.catalog-item:hover{
    height:215px;
}
```

**CSS for .supplier-info**

```
.catalog-item .supplier-info {
    color: #656262;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #656262;
    display:none;
}
.catalog-item:hover > div.supplier-info{
    display: block;
}
```

**EDIT**
For more smoothly effects (with opacity - take a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5dnsLdj/3/)**)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5dnsLdj/1/)**

Comment: Yes, perfect. And if you set `.catalog-item { vertical-align: top }` it will stop jumping around. *See fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/v5dnsLdj/4/   Thanks! And good idea with the animation, looks much better ;)

Comment: This seems like a much better approach indeed. +1

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Thank you! :) @AlbatrossCafe I've also added a version with `opacity` , for smoother transitions.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your css:

```
.supplier-info  {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.catalog-item:hover .supplier-info  {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/q8csa10v/4/

**--EDIT--**

To remove the **extra space below the divs**, you can:

**1)** Remove the current border property of the `catalog-item` and change it's height to `215px;`

**2)** Wrap the image in a `.item-img` div and add borders to it.

**3)** Add borders to the third box too.

**4)** Remove `bottom:0` from the **Product-Info** div and add borders for that div too.

Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/q8csa10v/13/

Comment: ah yes. I was using display which I forgot essentially removes the HTML from the view. *This is close.* Is it possible so that when it is hidden the main-box height shortens to remove that extra space at the bottom?